# Computer vision, Point Pattern Matching

Tags: opencv, pattern-matching

In Opencv, I know that matching can be done by computing the descriptors from some feature detector. But what about when input is only X,Y and radius coordinates of a circle..
Get anybody point me a direction?

Comment: Can you make or train a synthetic target?

Answer (score 0):

I would say Hough Transforms is your best bet and there is the [cvHoughCircles](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=cvhoughcircles#CvSeq%2a%20cvHoughCircles%28CvArr%2a%20image,%20CvMemStorage%2a%20circleStorage,%20int%20method,%20double%20dp,%20double%20minDist,%20double%20param1,%20double%20param2,%20int%20minRadius,%20int%20maxRadius%29) method for that.

Comment: I have two sets of data. This data consists in X, Y and Radius of circles. What i want to do is to find the matchs using all the possible information in the two sets. Can it be done with FLANN? How?

Comment: Hmmm...never used FLANN before...but I see there's an entry in the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html) so surely it can be done.